# HyperLink or Link on PivotGridField with DevExpress - ASP.NET With C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, devexpress

[This shows the lots count of every step in the process of manufacturing the product, but I want to know if its possible to make a link to know which lots are included in this lots count, I'm using dx:pivotGridField, inside a dx:ASPxPivotGrid all with devexpress, the only thing that I don't know is that if a can put a link on every single data of that column, click on any number to send me a chart with the info of that lots.

Thanks!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijTnR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *ValueTemplate*

```
<dx:PivotGridField Area="ColumnArea"  AreaIndex="0" FieldName="ConsumptionDate" ID="fieldConsumptionMonth">
                                <ValueTemplate>
                                        <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="ASPxHyperLink1" runat="server"  ondatabinding="OnHyperLinkDataBinding" NavigateUrl='test.aspx' />
                                </ValueTemplate>
                            </dx:PivotGridField>
```

And then set the text in the backend

```
protected void OnHyperLinkDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ASPxHyperLink link = (ASPxHyperLink)sender;
        link.Text = ((PivotGridFieldValueTemplateContainer)link.Parent).Text;
    }
```

Comment: that's Works, thanks Victor Hugo, but only the header have a link, but I want that every result in every cells have the option to put a link, on every register.

Comment: Got it, I didn't notice about that, I gave you +1, but back to the question, I only have 5 fields and only the link apply for the header the content doesn't have the link, I mean I have a column named Lots_Count, the name "Lots_Count" has the hyperlink, but the values of this columns doesn't have that option, sorry if I can't express my main a idea

Comment: @EduardoMoreno, it is hard for you to explain your goal here and hard for me to understand it, please open a new question with a detailed description of your problem and a picture maybe, tag it with devexpress and I will try to answer it.